# Steps on how to push segue to tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am having issues displaying data in a tableview from a push segue. How do you make data appear in the tableview from the push segue? Do I need to implement a delegate/protocol? What method would I add my logic to display the rows in the TableViewController from the push segue. I able to navigate to the tableview and back to the button sort view controllers.

Can someone show me the process similar how I wrote My Logic? I am stuck on step 4. If you have a easier way to execute please let me know.

**Controllers I am trying to coordinate.**

- "EventFeedController.m " TableViewController executed from Tab Bar Controller. This shows the events.
- " ButtonSort.m " to push segue to EventFeedController.m
- AppDelegate.m has array.

**My Logic...**

In the storyboard.

1. Control drag from UIButton in ButtonSort directly to EventsFeedViewController (not to the navigationcontroller but directly to the view EventViewController itself. ). (Not sure if I should control drag to view controller or the navigation controller of EventsfeedViewController)
2. Select push segue from popup of the control drag
3. Give Button a identifier of Button01 (This would find items array where eventFeed.eventType = @"Festival";) So for clarity Button01 = Find events with eventFeed.eventType = @"Festival";
4. Step I am stuck on. Not sure how to access or display the array created in AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions paragraph. I thought cellForRowAtIndexPath in EventsFeedViewController would be responsible for being called and displaying the rows again.

**Sample of array code AppDelegate.m**

Events array created AppDelegate.m. I need to pull the event when clicking the push button segue.

```
_events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

//***************************************
// Event feed related area
//***************************************
SDEventsFeed *eventFeed = [[SDEventsFeed alloc] init];
eventFeed.eventTitle = @"Event Fest Test 1";
eventFeed.eventDescription = @"This is not to be missed";
eventFeed.eventStartTime = @"2:00 PM";
eventFeed.eventImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fest.jpg"];
eventFeed.eventType = @"Festival";
[_events addObject:eventFeed];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table view controller that you want to push to display the data, you will need to add a property to hold that data. Something like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyDataClass *myData;
```

Then in the view controller that you're pushing from (the one with the button that pushes the table view controller), you'll want to add a method `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. You can implement it in a way like the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifierFromStoryboard"]) {
        YourTableViewControllerClass *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        viewController.myData = self.myData;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'MyDataClass' what is that doing? I have a NSMutableArray in the TableViewController and can access that like 'viewController.events' but don't know how to get self.myData to populate the data. The events array is in AppDelegate.m. Any suggestions? @Gavin

Comment: It might be helpful to see more of your code. What is unclear to me is, is this _events array currently doing anything at all in any of your view controllers, or is it currently that you haven't figured out how to access it from even the first displayed one? Again, if you add more of your code it might be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

To pull the data from the AppDelegate you would need to do the following.

1. Make sure you import the AppDelegate.h into your class doing the segue.
2. You can create a NSMutableArray property in AppDelegate.h to hold the array data "eventArray".

This is just one possible solution.

ButtonSort.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Button01"]) {

    YourTableViewControllerClass *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    viewController.events = appDelegate.eventsArray;

 } 
}
```